# wamp - publish website - completely STUCK

Tags: wordpress, apache, wamp

MY site is here: www.tumolo.co.uk

It's a wordpress site - but the layout is BROKEN. It supposed to be displaying a countdown coming soon page - works locally, but not online!

I've got Wamp installed on Windows 10 laptop, i had it all working before, but i needed to reformat my laptop, now I cant remember what I did to get this site online working properly!

www.tumolo.co.uk/wp-admin is the link to log into wordpress, but that's broken too, it used to work!

I have edited my httpd.conf file, to show the following at the bottom:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www"
ServerName localhost
<Directory "C:\wamp\www">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Require local
</Directory>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\wordpress"
ServerName tumolo.co.uk
ServerAlias www.tumolo.co.uk
<Directory "C:\wamp\www\wordpress">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I've also TICKED rewrite_module, no idea why, but something I remembered I did before I think!

What am I missing please guys, I'm so close, just want to show my site online and any "sub sites" as well e.g. tumolo.co.uk/fcslfn is broken too, this used to display another site i built.

Thanks all.

Comment: I think your URLs aren't right anymore, you'll have to change it from localhost to a public ip or domain name. See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Worked a treat - thanks - so easy too!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to find and replace links in the database.
Go to phpmyadmin, choose your database -> sql query and put this as the query (replace corresponding links):

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://oldsite.com', 'http://newsite.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://oldsite.com','http://newsite.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://oldsite.com', 'http://newsite.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://oldsite.com','http://newsite.com');